# Código de lista não compilando bem

Tags: c++, lista, ponteiro, lista-encadeada, codeblocks

Olá.

Estou tentando aprender sobre ponteiros e listas e fiz um código que contém um menu e a opção de inserir quantos valores eu quiser. Eu fiz o código no codeblocks mais recente usando w10 e funcionou bem da forma que está, porém eu testei em outros pcs e em um ubuntu e vi que não compilou muito bem.

Ao selecionar a opção 2, em outros pcs a execução parava, e no ubuntu o menu reaparecia sem rodar a função.
Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef struct lista{

    int elemento; /* componente da lista */

    struct lista *proximo; /* Aponta para a proxima posicao de mémoria*/

}lista;

lista *primeiro, *atual, *NovaLista, *LiberaMemoria; /* Variaveis de manipulacao da lista*/

void ExcluiElemento();
void CriaLista();
void Imprimir();
void InserirElemento();
void liberamemoria(int numero);

int main(){

    int opcao;
    do{
        cout<<"1------------Criar Lista\n"
        <<"2------------Inserir Elemento na lista\n"
        <<"3-----------Imprimir Elementos da lista\n"
        <<"4------------Exlcuir Elementos da lista \n\n";
        cin>>opcao;

        switch(opcao){

            case 1:

                CriaLista();
                break;

            case 2:

                InserirElemento();
                break;

            case 3:

                Imprimir();
                break;

            case 4:

                ExcluiElemento();
                break;

        }

    }while(opcao != 5);

    return 0;
}

void liberamemoria(int numero){
    atual=primeiro;
    LiberaMemoria=primeiro;
    while(LiberaMemoria!=NULL){
        if(LiberaMemoria->elemento != numero){
            atual=LiberaMemoria;
            LiberaMemoria=LiberaMemoria-> proximo;

        }else{
            if(LiberaMemoria==atual){
                primeiro = atual->proximo;
                liberamemoria(numero);
                break;

            }else if(LiberaMemoria->proximo==NULL){
                atual->proximo=NULL;

                break;
            }else{
                atual->proximo=LiberaMemoria->proximo;
                liberamemoria(numero);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(LiberaMemoria);

}

void ExcluiElemento(){

    int numero;

    if(primeiro==NULL){
        cout<<"Lista vazia\n\n";
    }else{
        cout<<" Digite o elemento que deseja excluir da lista: ";
        cin>>numero;

        liberamemoria(numero);
    }
}
void CriaLista(){
    if(primeiro==NULL){
        primeiro=(struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(lista)); /* Cria um nó na lista*/
        cout<<"lista criada com sucesso. \n\n";
    }else{
        cout << "lista ja criada. \n\n";
    }
}

void Imprimir(){

     if(primeiro==NULL){

        cout<<" lista vazia";
    }else{

        atual=primeiro;
        cout<< "Elementos Inseridos na Lista\n\n";

        while(atual!=NULL){
            cout<<atual->elemento<< "\n\n";
            atual=atual->proximo;
        }
    }

}

void InserirElemento(){
    int i;
    atual=primeiro;

    if(atual==NULL){ /* Verifica se a lista foi criada*/
        cout << "lista ainda nao criada \n\n";
    }else{
        while(i!=0){

            while(atual->proximo!=NULL){
                atual=atual->proximo;
            }

            cout<<"Insira um elemento na lista: \t";
            cin>>atual->elemento;


            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"deseja inserir outro elemento na lista 1/0:  \t";
            cin>>i;
            if(i==1){
                NovaLista=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
                atual->proximo=NovaLista;
            }
            cout<<"\n";


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Fire,

Então, vamos por partes:

**Primeiro: pular a função de inserir elemento**

isso está acontecendo pois você disse que a condição pra entrar no `while` é que a variável `i` seja diferente de 0, porém você não a inicializou, então por isso você não entra no loop de inserção.

Código corrigido:

```
void InserirElemento(){
  int i=1; //Inicializando a variável para garantir que ela entre no loop
  atual=primeiro;

  if(atual==NULL){ /* Verifica se a lista foi criada*/
      cout << "lista ainda nao criada \n\n";
  }else{
      while(i!=0){

          while(atual->proximo!=NULL){
              atual=atual->proximo;
          }

          cout<<"Insira um elemento na lista: \t";
          cin>>atual->elemento;


          cout<<"\n";
          cout<<"deseja inserir outro elemento na lista 1/0:  \t";
          cin>>i;
          if(i==1){
              NovaLista=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
              atual->proximo=NovaLista;
          }
          cout<<"\n";


      }
  }
}
```

**Segundo: Porquê meu código não funciona no Ubunto?**

Windows e Linux são sistemas operacionais diferentes, e, portanto, utilizam arquiteturas diferentes. No caso, seu código não roda por um problema de compatibilidade, Não vou entrar muito em detalhes pois é um assunto um pouco complexo, mas para resolver esse problema você pode buscar os comandos de C++ que funcionam em Linux e substituir no seu código.

Espero ter ajudado!

Abraços!